# Java Spring MVC application - How to resolve this warning?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-mvc-test

I have tried the solutions which were discussed in other discussions but nothing worked for me. Any help is appreciated

Here is my Web.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>spring-mvc-crud-demo</display-name>
  <absolute-ordering />

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-crud-demo-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Here is my spring-mvc-crud-demo.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <!-- Add support for component scanning -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.luv2code.springdemo" />

    <!-- Add support for conversion, formatting and validation support -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <!-- Define Spring MVC view resolver -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Step 1: Define Database DataSource / connection pool -->
    <bean id="myDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
          destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web_customer_tracker?useSSL=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC" />
        <property name="user" value="springstudent" />
        <property name="password" value="springstudent" /> 

        <!-- these are connection pool properties for C3P0 -->
        <property name="initialPoolSize" value="5"/>
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20" />
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="30000" />
    </bean>  

    <!-- Step 2: Setup Hibernate session factory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.luv2code.springdemo.entity" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
           <props>
              <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
              <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
           </props>
        </property>
   </bean>    

    <!-- Step 3: Setup Hibernate transaction manager -->
    <bean id="myTransactionManager"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Step 4: Enable configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="myTransactionManager" />

    <!-- Add support for reading web resources: css, images, js, etc ... -->
    <mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"></mvc:resources>



</beans>
```

This is my controller class

```
package com.springdemo.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import com.springdemo.dao.CustomerDAO;
import com.springdemo.entity.Customer;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/customer")
public class CustomerController {

    // need to inject the customer dao
    @Autowired
    private CustomerDAO customerDAO;

    @RequestMapping("/list")
    public String listCustomers(Model theModel) {

        // get customers from the dao
        List<Customer> theCustomers = customerDAO.getCustomers();

        // add the customers to the model
        theModel.addAttribute("customers", theCustomers);

        return "list-customers";
    }

}
```

However on going to http://localhost:8080/web-customer-tracker/

it returns a 404 error.

```
May 13, 2019 1:37:43 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/resources/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0'
May 13, 2019 1:37:43 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization completed in 11889 ms
May 13, 2019 1:37:43 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
May 13, 2019 1:37:43 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
May 13, 2019 1:37:43 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in [14,797] milliseconds
May 13, 2019 1:37:48 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/web-customer-tracker/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

Here is my project structure

[image: Project structure]

Comment: Share the pom.xml. You need add 'web-customer-tracker' as your final package name which will be deployed in server.

Comment: Hi Oomph this application is build using spring and hibernate, maven is not used

Comment: then How are you downloading/managing the dependancies if you are not using maven?

Comment: I am using Spring annotation to manage dependencies

Comment: the how are you creating your final deployable package?

Comment: Sorry I did not get your question. I am basically building web application which includes all CRUD features. Browser -> Controller -> Services->Data Access Object-> Database is the flow of the application. Was this helpful?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193233/discussion-between-oomph-fortuity-and-ashish-shah).

Comment: If this is a new application, avoid both the legacy Servlet configuration and JSP if at all possible. Spring Boot makes all of your configuration here unnecessary, and Thymeleaf is much easier to test.

Comment: I already build the application using Spring, just one step away from working project. So trying to solve this warning.

Comment: Try the URL:

http://localhost:8080/web-customer-tracker/customer/list  Your controller is mapped to that URL, you have nothing mapped to the root url /. Or it should be even : http://localhost:8080/customer/list because in the web.xml you map the root url to your only servlet

Comment: I tried changing the URL, still getting same warnings

Comment: you are scanning `com.luv2code.springdemo` package, however your controller is in `com.springdemo.controller`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the end-point of http://localhost:8080/web-customer-tracker
If you want to call the Customer List end-point you should call  http://localhost:8080/customer/list

If you still want to use the context-path 'web-customer-tracker', you need to add the following configuration into application.properties

```
server.servlet.context-path=/web-customer-tracker
```

Then you can call customer list using http://localhost:8080/web-customer-tracker/customer/list

Answer (score 0):

configure that url in servlet-mapping as

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/web-customer-tracker*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Then you can call customer list using http://localhost:8080/web-customer-tracker/customer/list